# Difference between uid and unique id

Tags: mysql

I am learning about login system in Android, PHP, and MySQL from [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/).

I'm confused about `uid` and `uniquid_id`. What is the use of `unique_id` if it already has a `uid`?

This is the MySQL query that has uid and unique_id looks like. Can someone tell me what is the difference and the functions of `uid` and `unique_id`?

```
create table users(
uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
name varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(100) not null unique,
encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
salt varchar(10) not null,
created_at datetime,
updated_at datetime null
);
```

Comment: uid and unique_id are just column names... how they are used is based on your application! Perhaps unique_id is a GUID, and uid is a pseudokey?

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused. They are just names and not functions, as we all have got one.

You cannot just guess, what could be expansion of `uid`. They are just column names.

For example, `uid` might refer a user id

Comment: if uid refer to id, so what the function of unique_id?. thank you.
@Amit Joki